# Are the Irish laws written in the Irish language?

Tags: irish

Are the Irish laws written in the Irish language these days?
Or was there any moment in history when the laws were written/translated in the Irish language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Constitution](https://www.constitution.ie/Documents/Bhunreacht_na_hEireann_web.pdf) is bilingual, and the Irish version take precedence in case of conflict. Some Acts such as the Adoption Act 2010 are passed in [English](http://www.oireachtas.ie/documents/bills28/acts/2010/a2110.pdf) and [Irish](http://www.oireachtas.ie/documents/bills28/acts/2010/a2110i.pdf), but some are [English only](http://www.oireachtas.ie/documents/bills28/acts/2003/a12003.pdf). Most are bilingual. I don't think any are passed only in Irish, but that's based on manual inspection.

Comment: Thanks, and how many laws are approximately passed in English only? (as a percentage)